# reinversion of control using longjmp

Tags: c, inversion-of-control, undefined-behavior, setjmp

I'm trying to implement reinversion of control in c using longjmp, currently i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf env;
int arg;
typedef void (*fptr)(int);
fptr callback;
void cb(int a)
{
    arg = a;
    longjmp(env, 1);
}
#define cont1(f, x) do { if(!setjmp(env)) { f(x, &cb); return; } } while(0)

void callback_func(int num, fptr cb)
{
    printf("in a func, num = %d\n", num);
    callback  = cb;
}

void task1()
{
    printf("before continuation\n");
    cont1(callback_func, 7);
    printf("after continuation\n");
}

void task2()
{
    printf("in thread 2\n");
    (*callback)(5);
}

int main()
{
    task1();
    task2();
    printf("arg = %d\n", arg);
    return 0;
}
```

And my question is: doesn't this invoke undefined behavior or could cause any problem in real world use and if yes, then is there any better way to do this?

Comment: There are certainly ways to write clearer code than this one, but why do you think it could have an error that leads to UB? Perhaps you could give us a first analysis of what is right and what could be wrong yourself?

Comment: As far as I understand, reinversion of control relies on continuations, or something equivalent.  Although using `setjmp() / longjmp()` has some similarities to a continuation, it is not an equivalent.  I don't think C or its standard library has an equivalent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: This is correct. But you can construct something like an equivalent using threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program has undefined behavior. See C11 7.13.2.1 *The longjmp function* (emphasis mine):

> If there has been no such invocation, or if the invocation was from another thread of execution, **or if the function containing the invocation of the setjmp macro has terminated execution<sup>248</sup> in the interim**, or if the invocation of the setjmp macro was within the scope of an identifier with variably modified type and execution has left that scope in the interim, **the behavior is undefined**.
>
> 248) For example, by **executing a return statement** or because another longjmp call has caused a transfer to a setjmp invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.

At the time you `cb` calls `longjmp`, the function which invoked `setjmp` to fill `env`, `task1`, has returned. Thus calling `longjmp` is undefined.

The C language has no means to do what you're trying to do except for (now with C11) threads, using condition variables to control which thread runs.

Comment: Well but `longjmp` from another thread is undefined behavior as well, so how would you implement this using threads without violating this rule?

Comment: You wouldn't `longjmp` from another thread. You would just use condvars to start/stop threads according to which code you want to "transfer control" to.